# How to select a text within the Highlighted text in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I want to select part of the highlighted text in **Adobe Acrobat**. By using the select tool, when I want to select part of highlighted text, it selects all the highlighted text. For example as in the picture depicted,I want to select just first sentence from the highlighted text. Is it possible or a way to do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn on the "Edit Text & Images" in the "Tools" panel in Adobe Acrobat, you should be able to select text inside highlighted region and right-click to do cut/copy/paste. I just tried on my laptop using Acrobat 11.0. Hope this can solve your problem. Not sure if Adobe Reader can do the same.

Comment: I have Acrobat Pro 9. I couldn't find it. Is it a new feature in Pro 11?

Comment: Yeah, it's working. But somehow dangerous! Maybe the text eliminated or changed without my notice!

Comment: I don't think there be another solution. So, the bounty is yours ;)

Comment: @hamed: I agree it is somehow dangerous, but cannot think of better solution.

Comment: @Prasanna: I think Acrobat changed the interface since version X, this function should be called something like "TouchUp Text" before.

Answer (score 6):

Some workaround for this very old bug.

**Toggle Read Mode**

On OS X: Ctrl-CMD-H

On windows: Ctrl-H

**Use block selection**

Shift + Alt + Drag-select

Comment: In "Read Mode", I was able to simply select text within a highlight (block selection was not what I needed).

Comment: same. Using read mode allows selection. No block selection necessary.

Comment: This is far better than the accepted answer.

You can combine *block selection* and Shift-clicking to get regular selections within highlights (without toggling *Read Mode*): 1. Block Select the first word (Shift+Alt+Drag/Doubleclick) of the desired selection, 2. Shift-click the end of the selection. A workaround with minimal compromise!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but not perfect. Click with the mouse on the text before or after which is not selected to place there the cursor. Now use the keyboard keys ↑ , ↓ , → , ← to move the cursor to the part of the area you want to select and hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you move ↑ , ↓ , → , ←  on your keyboard to select the part of the highlighted text you are interested in.

Comment: Isn't anyway to do this with mouse cursor? I need to select the text so many times.

Comment: @hamed This is the only way to do it in Adobe Reader. There is no hidden option because this was probably not intended by the developers at Adobe. You could report this as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Devid's solution will work for quotes at the beginning or end of highlighted text, but not more generally.

If you are tied to Adobe software for highlighting, but are willing to try another PDF reader for reading and selecting text, the desired result works in SumatraPDF: I am able to take a file that contained highlights in Adobe Reader and use SumatraPDF to select and copy any text within the highlighted text.

Comment: I know with the other pdf viewers I can do this, but adobe acrobat has a lot of feature that they don't have. There should be some option in adobe! no?